# Eclipse throwing an error while running entire folder

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, pydev

When I run an entire folder with some pydev module, I am get a debugger error in Eclipse:

```
0.06s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
```

How to overcome this?

Comment: This looks like a Warning, not an Error, and one that says what to do about it if you want to no longer see it.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, this is a warning.

You can silence it by setting an environment variable:

`PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1`

-- you can do that at the `Environment` tab in your preferences `PyDev > Interpreters > Python Interpreter`

Or you can pass `-Xfrozen_modules=off` in your launch configuration so that you can debug the frozen modules.